# Kivy screen management

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language, kivymd, kivy-recycleview

**how to make the main and not the shop open when the program starts**

the program has a menu and three screens. i need to open the main screen when i start it and not the shop

and maybe there is also an option to remove icons from the menu so that the menu is text or vice versa

main.py

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.utils import get_color_from_hex
from kivy.core.text import LabelBase

Window.size = (430, 930)

class ShopScreen(Screen):
    pass

class ItemsScreen(Screen):
    pass

class HomeScreen(Screen):
    Builder.load_file("Home.kv")

class WindowManager(FloatLayout):
    pass

class MainApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        self.theme_cls.theme_style = "Dark"
        sm = ScreenManager()
        sm.add_widget(ShopScreen(name='menu'))
        sm.add_widget(ItemsScreen(name='items'))
        sm.add_widget(HomeScreen(name='main'))
        Builder.load_file("main.kv")
        return WindowManager()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    LabelBase.register(name="Press Start 2P",
                    fn_regular='./font/PressStart2P-Regular.ttf')
    MainApp().run()
```

main.kv

```
#: import get_color_from_hex kivy.utils.get_color_from_hex
<WindowManager>:
    MDBottomNavigation: 
        font_name: "./font/PressStart2P-Regular.ttf"
        panel_color: get_color_from_hex("#1B1B1B")
        text_color_active: 1, 1, 0, 1
        MDBottomNavigationItem:
            icon: 'home'
            name: 'shop'
            text: 'МАГАЗИН'
 
        MDBottomNavigationItem:
            icon: 'home'
            name: 'main'
            text: 'ГОЛОВНА' 
            HomeScreen:
  
        MDBottomNavigationItem:
            icon: 'home'
            name: 'items'
            text: 'ХЕЛПЕРИ'
```

Comment: In your `build()` method, you create a `ScreenManager` instance and add 3 `Screens` to it. But you do nothing with that `sm`. None of your `Screens` will appear.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer:

Move the line of the screen you want to start up first to the top position, like this:

```
class MainApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        self.theme_cls.theme_style = "Dark"
        sm = ScreenManager()
        sm.add_widget(HomeScreen(name='main'))
        sm.add_widget(ItemsScreen(name='items'))
        sm.add_widget(ShopScreen(name='menu'))
        Builder.load_file("main.kv")
        return WindowManager()
```

Long answer: At the beginning of the ScreenManager(), you are defining the order of the screens. You can't call those screens from other screens directly. Maybe this is what you want. However, here's an example of how you can achieve it:

```
class MainApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        self.theme_cls.theme_style = "Dark"
        sm = ScreenManager()
        sm.add_widget(HomeScreen(name='main'))
        sm.add_widget(ItemsScreen(name='items'))
        sm.add_widget(ShopScreen(name='menu'))

        return sm

        Builder.load_file("main.kv")
        return WindowManager()
```

When you are on another screen, you can use this code to switch to another screen.

```
# In another class, for example, a button event or somewhere else where you have access to the `MainApp` instance
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager

class SomeClass:
    def some_method(self):
        # Get the instance of MainApp and Access the ScreenManager of MainApp
        screen_manager = MainApp.get_running_app().screen_manager

        # Change the currently displayed screen to 'menu'
        screen_manager.current = 'menu'
```

I hope this was helpful.